# After running a bash script as root user, how can I have the script automatically force my user to exit root?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root

I have a bash script that must be run by the root user, however, I would like that script to force the user to exit root automatically. I know you exit root by typing 'exit' into the command line, but putting that into the bash script will just exit the script. Help is appreciated!

Comment: This question is perfect for superuser.

Comment: You could run the script with `.` instead of `sh script.sh` so that lines are pasted into current terminal instead of having it run in separate subshell. Better yet, use `sudo`...

Comment: i like using:  `source`

Comment: Then at the end of your script, just include `exit` (but if sourced as normal user it will close terminal)

Comment: Use sudo to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the suggestion given by William

```
$sudo ./your.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sudo -v` at the start of your script to ask for the sudo password.
And `sudo -k` at the end to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stick something like this to the beginning of your script:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" == root ]; then
   echo "ERROR: root cannot run this script"
   exit 1
fi
```

That will enforce that you can run the script only as a regular user and when the script exits you will be the regular user again. Then put a sudo in front of every command that in the script that does need root permission. With caching sudo credentials the user of your script needs to enter his/her pwd only once.